# Is there a Java class providing task chaining with specific delay?

Tags: java

I'm currently looking for a Java class or library that facilitates the chaining of tasks with specific delay between them. To clarify, I need to execute a sequence of tasks (taskA, taskB, taskC, etc.), where each task starts after the previous one completes, and there's a specific delay between each task's completion and the start of the next one. (

For instance, I'm looking for functionality similar to this hypothetical class, Foo:

```java
Foo foo = new Foo(Duration.ofSeconds(1)); // 1 second delay
foo.submit(taskA); // This should run without delay
foo.submit(taskB); // This should run after 1 second
foo.submit(taskC); // This should run after 2 seconds
```

I've explored ScheduledExecutorService and TimerTask, but these classes don't seem to provide this exact behavior out of the box.

Is there an existing Java class or library that offers this kind of task chaining with customizable delays between each task? Maybe I can implement this by my-self, but just looking for it before I do.

Thank you in advance for any insights or guidance.

p.s. If you're thinking of Reactor's delayElements, that's correct. However, I'm specifically seeking a solution in a more traditional manner.

### EDIT

As you're being confused, I'll explain it in more detail. `ScheduledExecutorService` is a good choice to schedule **a single task** which should run repeat repeatably, but that's not what I want.

For example, Let's say I have `foo` class declared as a singleton.

```java
class SingletonFoo {
    private static Foo foo = new Foo(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

    public static void submitTask(Runnable runnable) {
        foo.submit(runnable)
    }
}
```

And then, multiple threads gonna submit tasks to `SingletonFoo` and don't care the result and when to be executed (which also means threads shouldn't be blocked)

```java
void thread_1() {
    // ... do something
    SingletonFoo.submitTask(taskA);
    // and keep going
}

void thread_2() {
    // ... do something
    SingletonFoo.submitTask(taskB);
    // and keep going
}

void thread_3() {
    // ... do something
    SingletonFoo.submitTask(taskC);
    // and keep going
}
```

In this case, if thread 1, 2, 3 run sequentially, submitted task by thread_3 would be executed after 2 second.

I know that this is not an usual case, so just looking for any existing class provided by JDK or library. If it doesn't exist, that's okay. I just wanna know whether it exists.

Comment: I guess you might want to take a look at ScheduledExecutorService: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: As I mentioned, ScheduledExecutorService doesn't seem to fit my needs. Submitted tasks gonna run independently, right ?

Comment: How exactly is ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay not meeting your requirements?

Comment: I think he wants some of the Tasks to be blocking. But as far as I understand you would need a blocking queue of tasks to achieve this.

Comment: Why don't you simply use Thread.sleep()?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a recurring *single* task, you can use [ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-). It does exactly what you need:

> Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given delay between the termination of one execution and the commencement of the next.

If it's a sequence of *different* tasks, then I am not aware of such functionality out of the box. But you can implement a simplified version with the executor service and a `Queue` (or another collection).

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = //init service
Queue<Runnable> tasks = //taskA, taskB, etc.
boolean isFirst = true;
while (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
  long delay = isFirst ? 0 : 1;
  isFirst = false;
  //schedule 1st without delay, subsequent tasks with 1 second delay
  ScheduledFuture<?> future = service.schedule(tasks.poll(), delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  future.get();//wait until the task finishes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, **ScheduledExecutorService** sounds like what you really need
(first task without delay, the second one with 1 second delay, the third one with 2 seconds delay).

Consider this block of code and make required changes (e.g. you can wait without time out for tasks result before start the next one or you can use more than one thread if you need):

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    Runnable task1 = () -> System.out.printf("%s %s%n", LocalTime.now(), "task1");
    Runnable task2 = () -> System.out.printf("%s %s%n", LocalTime.now(), "task2");
    Runnable task3 = () -> System.out.printf("%s %s%n", LocalTime.now(), "task3");

    System.out.printf("%s is Current time %n", LocalTime.now());

    ScheduledFuture<?> future = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(task1, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    future = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(task2, 1_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    scheduledExecutorService.schedule(task3, 2_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
```

Output for code above is:

```
10:39:41.336626 is Current time 
10:39:41.342243 task1
10:39:42.347892 task2
10:39:44.354810 task3
```

As I see, it is actually what you have asked for.

**NB**: this example is quite simplified; you can utilize ***Collection*** of tasks and ***for loop*** in the same manner, I tried to deliver the main idea.

Comment: I think you may have meant "... in the same _manner_" 

Answer (score 1):

Using [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html):

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(taskA)
    .thenRunAsync(taskB,
        CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    .thenRunAsync(taskC,
        CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

Of course, you could also just sleep between them:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    try {
        taskA.run();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        taskB.run();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        taskC.run();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
});
```